# What **admissible** has to do in the inequation $I(L_x)\subset I(C_x)$

Tags: general-topology, ideals

$X$ is a topological space and $x=\{x_n\}\subset X$ is a sequence. $I$ is an ideal of

y ∈ X is called an **I-limit point** of x if there exists a set $M = \{m_1 < m_2 < m_3 < ···\} ⊂ \mathbb N$ such that $M \notin I$ and
$\lim_{k→∞} x_{m_k} = y$

y ∈ X is called an **I-cluster point** of x if for every open set U containing y, $\{n ∈ \mathbb N: x_n ∈ U\} \notin I$.

We denote by $I(C_x)$ and $I(L_x)$ the collections of all I-cluster points and all I-limit points of x, respectively.

Now I can easily prove that $I(L_x) ⊂ I(C_x)$.

> Let $y\in I(L_x).$ Then there is a set $M\notin I$ s.t. $\lim_{k→∞} x_{m_k} = y$ i.e. $\exists k\in \mathbb N$ s,.t for any given nbd $U$ $x_{m_n}\in U \forall n\ge k\implies \{n\in\mathbb N :x_n\in U\}\notin I\implies y\in I(C_x).$

Now, whether the ideal $I$  is admissible or not has not been used in this trivial proof. Is admissibility at all required or necessary here for the [this paper](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0166864112001812/1-s2.0-S0166864112001812-main.pdf?_tid=5720b23e-8bd8-11e6-aa03-00000aacb362&acdnat=1475767382_982b30028ef410cfbf756ec5ad277279) says *"For an
admissible ideal I, it is known that $I(L_x) ⊂ I(C_x)$"*  But this holds even without admissibility of the ideal.

> An ideal $I$ of $\mathbb N$ is called **admissible**  if every singleton $\{x\}$ is in $I.$

So, my question is why is "***admissible***"  mentioned here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your proof is incorrect: if $\mathscr{I}$ is not admissible, the fact that $M\notin\mathscr{I}$ does not imply that the cofinite subsets of $M$ are not in $\mathscr{I}$, and you need that implication in order for the argument to work. Here is a concrete counterexample.

Let $\mathscr{I}=\{I\subseteq\Bbb N:0\notin I\}$; $\mathscr{I}$ is an ideal of $\Bbb N$, but it’s not admissible. Let $X=\Bbb R$ with the usual topology. Define a sequence $x=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ by

$$x_n=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }n=0\\
2,&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}$$

Let $m_k=k$ for $n\in\Bbb N$, and let $M=\{m_k:k\in\Bbb N\}=\Bbb N$; then $M\notin\mathscr{I}$ (since $0\in M$), and $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_{m_k}=2$, so $2\in\mathscr{I}(L_x)$. But $\{n\in\Bbb N:x_n\in(1,3)\}=\Bbb N\setminus\{0\}\in\mathscr{I}$, so $2\notin\mathscr{I}(C_x)$, and therefore $\mathscr{I}(L_x)\nsubseteq\mathscr{I}(C_x)$.